# Why does Python behave this way?

Tags: python, boolean-logic

I am trying to figure out why python 2.7 behaves the way it does with the below code.

```
>>> a = True
>>> b = 5<6
>>> a == b
True
```

What is being tested here?
help much appreciated

Comment: 5 five is under 6, it's True. Is True is True ? Of course yes it's True.

Comment: `True == True` is indeed `True`

Comment: It is very much obvious that `a is True` and `5<6 == b is also True`. `a == b == True` which is True!! What else do you expect?

Comment: `=>` is not a valid Python operator. I get an error for the third line, did you copy it correctly? Did you mean `a == b >= True`?

Comment: right, i am mistaken there is nothing wrong with it => used here to refer to end result or sth

Comment: if you just used the interpreter and ran `b = (5<6)` and checked b's value it would be pretty obvious

Answer (score 0):

What us being tested is

```
(5<6) == True
```

Which is same as just testing

```
5<6
```

And it should be obvious that this is true, and Python agrees:

```
>>> 5<6
True
```

Writing it in the complex way shown in your question makes no sense really, at least as far as Python code us concerned. It's just bad code, unless there is some esoteric external requirement to write it like that.

---

If what you are wondering is, why does Python do that, then answer is: When you just run `python` command you get so called [REPL, or read-eval-print-loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop). REPL does just that: for every line of input you give it, it automatically prints the result of last expression in that line. And that `>>>` is Python's interactive prompt, indicating that you are in REPL mode.

Comment: no, sorry i was just writing it down, not in code as you can see, the => part I mean

Comment: @snejkatamie007 Edited answer, and added a wikipedia link for more information, in case your question was actually about REPL.